# Append query string in every request using Java/Java Spring web MVC / any other way

Tags: java

i want to append Query String to every request through out the application in java or Java Spring using session filter or any other way. please help me out its just driving me madly . Thanks in advance. :-) .

Example :

"http://www.using.com/GAOR/trackURL.do?15"

here 15 is the query string ,

but i need to add this query string to the next request like in below.
"http://www.using.com/GAOR/registrationRequestToStep1.do?15"
and go on until submit.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your provided links are not hosted yet?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I just given an example. actually its in localhost...... i am developing this for now. @Atish .

Comment: ROMIOX i tried to add it in sessionfilter , coz all the request will go through by meeting sessionfilter first.

Comment: Can you talk more about why it's 15? As 15 is parameter, if you really need to use 15 in every request handler, why not storage it in database one you get 15? I don't understand your design background.

Comment: PARIS , i guess my question is not more clear.... . 15 is just an example.... we can have anything there like 1/2/3/4/5/6 anything,. i want to generate the URL to specific source. let me tell u the example too. suppose from Highschool website i clicked on FB link , this FB link provided by FB to the Highschool only the request which is coming from Highschool only.then i can have counters on it. and i can store in the DB stating that, these many users from highschool source. or any other resource like from hospitals.ETC. is it clear ?.  please let me know..... else i can explain again ,.

Comment: please give me some solution folks. m stuck into it.......  :-( .